# Connecting Pentaho User Console to MS SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, pentaho

I'm trying to connect my Pentaho user console to MS SQL Server 2000. However, I always get this error:

```
Error connecting to database [sps]:
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database:(using class
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)
Invalid URL:jdbc:sqlserver://172.16.1.134:1433;databaseName=sys_v2;
integratedSecurity=false;user=sa;pass
```

Can anyone tell me why I get this error & how to solve it? TQ

Comment: is you jdbc driver is for MS SQL Server 2000? try jdbc driver from http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Comment: No. It's for other version for MS SQL SERVER. Do you know where I can find jdbc driver for this version? I try many time but everytime I want to download it says that the version for jdbc driver no longer exist.

Comment: yes, sql server 2000 is no longer supported by micsrosoft. But, pentaho is able to connect ms sql server 2000 using jdbc driver from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/

Comment: the jtds driver is better than the microsoft driver anyway - it actually works.

Comment: I already download jdbc driver from sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files. Can you teach me what changes I should do? Or tell me where I can find tutorial using this driver? Sorry if I seem like I'm stupid but I really don't know how. TQ.